# jQuery document.write?

Tags: jquery, html

Not sure if this is the correct place to post, But looking at the HTML5 boilerplate I have...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="_includes/js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Now I've read the second script is a fall back for if the first is down, but how? 
I always thought || was an OR operator and to me it just looks like it says when the page loads write an old jQuery lib to the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second half of the `||` operator is only evaluated if the left hand side is "falsey".  This is known as "short circuit evaluation" *

So when `window.jQuery` is `undefined`, it does the `document.write()`.

---

* `true || x  ==  true`, regardless of x's value, so a short circuit `||` operator given `true` for its left hand operand will skip evaluating the right hand of the expression since it doesn't change the result.

Conversely `false && x == false`.

Answer (score 1):

Because javascript is a falsy language, if jQuery is not available `window.jQuery` will return `undefined` which equates to `false`.

Therefore, the second part of the statement will be executed, which writes the `<script>` tag to the document containing the local backup version of jQuery.